# Pagination in FOREACH Loop

Tags: wordpress, foreach, pagination

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I'm trying to get pagination to work because I just have too many entries on the page (see link to sample page below), but am completely in the weeds.

This is for an archive page which lists custom posts based on a custom field (start date) and also drops them from the list when the start date passes.

Here's a sample page:
http://www.musicfestivaljunkies.com/festival-guide/us-festivals/

Here's the code I've been working with:

```
    <?php
    /**
    * Do we need to filter by event tag?
    */
    if(is_tax('event_tags') ) :
$tag = strip_tags( get_query_var('event_tags') );

$querystr = "
    SELECT wposts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta, $wpdb->terms wterms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy wtax, $wpdb->term_relationships wrels
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
    AND wterms.term_id = wtax.term_id
    AND wtax.term_taxonomy_id = wrels.term_taxonomy_id
    AND wrels.object_id = wposts.ID
    AND wterms.slug = '$tag'
    ";

    else:
$querystr = "
    SELECT wposts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id";
    endif;

    // Build the rest of the query, i.e. only get events with dates, and order newest first.
$querystr .= "
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'Date'
AND STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value,'%m/%d/%Y') >= CURDATE()
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wposts.post_type = 'events'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value,'%m/%d/%Y') ASC
";


$events = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

if ($events):
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($events as $post):
    global $post;
    setup_postdata($post);

    // Get a friendlier version of the date.
    $date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Date', true);
    $date = date_create($date);
    $date = date_format($date, 'jS F, Y');
    ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> - <?php echo $date; ?></li>      
<?php endforeach;
echo '</ul>';
    endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to get some seriously unique data, writing your own query is usually something to avoid in WordPress. In this case, you'll want to look into the get_posts() method ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts ). I'm not 100% sure exactly which parameters you'll need to accomplish your goals, but definitely start by looking at the 'post_type' argument, as well as 'meta_key' and 'meta_value', which you can use to find posts within a particular custom type that have a particular meta value set on them (it appears that's at least partially what you're looking to accomplish).

If this doesn't get you headed in the right direction, please let me know what you're trying to accomplish a little more specifically and maybe I can clarify further.

UPDATE: This section of the get_posts() doc should help specifically with custom fields, and as a bonus it's using a custom post_type as well: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters